# TeeChart + Series Legend CheckBox

Tags: activex, teechart

Currently I Am displaying CheckBox in Legends.Is there any Event using which I can Find out on which Legend user have clicked.

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: Given that your other questions are about TeeChart ActiveX I assume it's the same with this one. For future questions please add the tag of the platform in which you use TeeChart. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the *OnClickLegend* event, for example:

```
Private Sub TChart1_OnClickLegend(ByVal Button As TeeChart.EMouseButton, ByVal Shift As TeeChart.EShiftState, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
    Me.Caption = "Clicked legend item: " & CStr(TChart1.Legend.Clicked(X, Y))
End Sub
```